# Issue with Highcharts: Blue bars not visible within green bars

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a Highcharts bar graph where I want the blue bars to be visible within the green bars, but the blue bars are not showing up.
[image: I expect something like as shown in the image but with a blue bar(column) inside green bar(column)], but I'm not getting the desired result.

Here is the relevant code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/anibha88/yk7jupd1/3/

`Highcharts.chart('container', { chart: { type: 'column' }, title: { text: '' }, credits: { enabled: false }, xAxis: { categories: ['1-2024', '2-2024', '3-2024', '4-2024', '5-2024', '6-2024', '7-2024', '8-2024', '9-2024', '10-2024', '11-2024', '12-2024'], }, yAxis: [{ min: 0, title: { text: 'Hello' } }, { min: 0, title: { text: '' }, }], legend: { shadow: false }, tooltip: { shared: true }, plotOptions: { column: { grouping: false, shadow: false, borderWidth: 0 } }, series: [ { name: "Plants", data: [81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81], color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0], // Blue color for demand data pointPadding: 0.4, pointPlacement: 0.2, yAxis: 1 }, { name: "Animals", data: [300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300], color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2], // Green color for capacity data pointPadding: 0.3, pointPlacement: 0.2, yAxis: 1 }] });`

Thank you in advance,

I've tried adjusting the pointPadding and pointWidth properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you have given both series the same `yAxis`. As the green bars have a larger value and are placed on top of the blue bars, they end up covering the blue bars completely.

To fix, add a `zIndex` property to your "Plants" series:

```
series: [ {
  name: "Plants",
  data: [81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81],
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
  pointPadding: 0.4,
  pointPlacement: 0.2,
  yAxis: 1,
  zIndex:99, // <---- Add this
},
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adv4rqsf/